# Load, then add in assembly

Tags: microcontroller, arm, assembly

Im trying to load 2 values in assembly under the tm4c1294ntpcd (Cortex M4) then add it with the next code

```
    .global main
        .text
main
        BL  LRut

LRut
        LDR r5,=2172428;
        LDR r6,=0x7CD32A58;
        ADD r0,r5,r6;
        STR r0,[r1];


END
```

But it keeps saying errors like Unknown Marker, Unexpected trailing operand(s), and Bad term expression on the LDR lines, isn't the syntaxis

```
LDR <Rd>, =<numeric constant>
```

Then what its wrong?

Comment: Which assembler and which arguments to run it are you using?

Comment: Could be something simple, like required `#` in front of numeric constants.

Comment: Provide a link (or links, if needed) to the assembler manual (which you should have read, already.) It will probably describe these error messages and also give you some reasoning about why they occur. It will also discuss the proper syntax.

Comment: Might be the trailing semicolon but the assembler documentation is the place for the answer.

Comment: @domen , Im using the code composer studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LDR = trick is pseudo code.  Assembly language is defined by the assembler, the program you run to read your file.  No reason to assume any two assemblers define the same assembly language, usually they are pretty close but have differences.  pseudo instruction/code like this is not necessarily something you would expect to be supported everywhere, it is not a real instruction..thumb

```
hello:
    ldr r0,=0x12345678
    b hello
```

gives

```
00000000 <hello>:
   0:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (4 <hello+0x4>)
   2:   e7fd        b.n 0 <hello>
   4:   12345678
```

the pseudo instruction results in this case of a pc-relative load and some data in a pool.  If the value where something a single instruction could do

```
.thumb
hello:
    ldr r0,=1
    b hello

00000000 <hello>:
   0:   f04f 0001   mov.w   r0, #1
   4:   e7fc        b.n 0 <hello>
```

it just produces that instead, which makes it a nice feature.  But in general you need to do it yourself:

```
.thumb
hello:
    ldr r0,there
    b hello
there:
.word 0x12345678


00000000 <hello>:
   0:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (4 <there>)
   2:   e7fd        b.n 0 <hello>

00000004 <there>:
   4:   12345678
```

same as this

```
00000000 <hello>:
   0:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (4 <hello+0x4>)
   2:   e7fd        b.n 0 <hello>
   4:   12345678
```

because of where I put the constant.  If your assembler doesnt support such syntax then you need to find the syntax your assembler supports.  Some flavor of putting  a label with whatever the syntax is for defining a word, then whatever the syntax is for doing a pc-relative load of the contents at that label into the register.

Answer (score 2):

The assembler in Code Composer Studio does not use the "=" to indicate a literal operand to an LDR instruction. The gnu assembler does use the "=" but I don't know about other tools.

However, you need additional directives to indicate that you are writing an ARM Thumb-2 function.

There are other problems with your code, but we'll give you time to think about those and ask a specific question.